# Hide <tr> based on ID

Tags: jquery, html

I have a page consisting of several `<div>` elements and each `<div>` element has several `<tr>` tags. These `<tr>` tags are added dynamically but all get a unique ID.

Now when the user picks a certain value from a dropdownbox I want to hide all the `<tr>` tags that does not match the users choice.

This allows me to get the ID of the option the user has chosen.

```
$('#groupDropDownBox option:selected').attr('id');
```

And this selects all the `<tr>` tags inside the `<div>`.

```
$('#reviewGroupsDiv tr')
```

Now how would I go about hiding all `<tr>` tags that does now have the ID that the user has selected?

Appreciate any assistance!

Comment: I would rethink having TR's inside DIV's to start with. Table inside a div, sure. Parts of a table inside divs, bad idea.

Comment: Those TR tags are actually appended to a table that is then appended to the DIV =) But I see your point.

Comment: You need to provide us with more of your code. At a guess, you should be using `$('#groupDropDownBox').val()` instead of `attr('id')` to get the value from the `<select>` tag.

Comment: @KirkBeard the selector works. .val() would get the name of it, .attr('id') get the ID I need. What I need help with is how to hide all TR's if I have the TR's effected and the ID that is not to be hidden.

Comment: "all TR tags that does now have the ID" — Did you typo "now" for "not" or do you have (invalid) duplicate IDs?

Comment: Not sure if it's still true but Jquery used to have problems hiding table elements

Comment: "Those TR tags are actually appended to a table that is then appended to the DIV" — So why are you trying to hide the individual trs instead of the whole table?

Comment: People downvote questions so easily. Scares people away from using this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide the `<tr>` with the selected ID, you simply select it by its id:

`$(selectedId).hide()`

If you want to hide everything BUT the selected ID, you can use the jQuery [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector to select all elements from a certain type without the one that has your desired ID:

`$('tr').not(selectedId).hide()`

Comment: Thank you sir. This is what I was looking for. $('tr').not($('#groupDropDownBox option:selected').attr('id')).hide()

Will now do what I need!

Comment: -1 This will throw `ReferenceError: selectedId is not defined`. And even if `selectedId` was defined (which you were lazy not to), it won't work, because in jQuery, an ID should start with a `#` (for example `#hello` where `hello` comes from something like `<p id="hello">any text here</p>`, and this answer doesn't mention that.